# Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have no idea how i can render this JSON on logcat :[image]

The source code to get data from firebase realtime database :

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("hotel");

myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

It says error like this :

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

I've tried some tutorial, but i can't find one. Also, i try this :

```
HashMap value = DataSnapshot.getValue(HashMap.class);
```

It ended up error as well. How should i render this HashMap data ?

Comment: What does `myRef` point to?

Comment: it is database reference, you can see it on my question. i've just edited it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are getting **HashMap** of **String** as key and **Object** as Value so map it into something like below.

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + map);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

or we can get this parsed into some Model instead of an object.

**update**
use this to parse

```
 Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Comment: I still got error : `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.HashMap has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead`

Comment: Then I need you Json what you have posted in the string

Comment: i just want to read data from database. I didn't include post yet.

Comment: it's hard to tell what model you should follow without knowing which parent tag you are getting as database reference in code and full json

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `hotel` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, to get those values, please use the following code

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference hotelRef = rootRef.child("hotel");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String address = ds.child("address").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", address + " / " + name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
hotelRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Surubaya / Hotel Suridan
Bandung / Hotel Santika
//and so on
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it later

Comment: Ok and keep me posted.